# Pulling data from SQL database, displaying in label in VB app

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm working on an application where I need to pull info from a SQL Server database and display it in a label.

In the application, I'm tracking information for members of a volleyball team. When the roster was created in the database, I just made the primary key "PlayerID" an identity, so I don't have every player ID memorized the way I would if I was using, say, jersey numbers. Because of that, I want to pull that player ID from the database and display it on a certain form within the application next to the corresponding player name.

I already have a label, `lblPlayer1`, that displays the player's name. I then created another label, `lblPlayer1ID`, that will display the ID pulled from the database.

Here's my code:

```
Dim player1ID As Integer

Dim player1 As String
player1 = lblPlayer1.Text

Dim vballconnection As New SqlConnection
    vballconnection.ConnectionString = "[my connection string is here]"

Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    cmd1.Connection = vballconnection
    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT PlayerID FROM Player WHERE FirstName = '" & player1 & "'"
    vballconnection.Open()

Try
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
        If myreader.Read() Then
            lblPlayer1ID.Text = myreader.GetValue(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

vballconnection.Close()
```

I also tried setting the Try/Catch up like this:

```
Try
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
        If myreader.Read() Then
            player1ID = myreader.GetValue(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    lblPlayer1ID.Text = player1ID.ToString()
```

The problem is that my `lblPlayer1ID` isn't displaying a value. When I run the application, the label still just shows the default "Label1" text. I've double-checked that all the labels are properly named.

I have an identical situation on another form within the application where I'm also pulling info from the database and displaying it in a label, and it's working fine there. Can't figure out what the problem is in this case.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through and find out where the unexpected behavior occurs.   In the meantime, think about what you want to happen when there are two players with the same first name.

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries immediately. They way you have coded this is a text book example of sql injection vulnerability. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, guys. I figured out the problem - I just had everything under the wrong event handler!

Answer (score 0):

please change your try to this

```
Try
     lblPlayer1ID.Text = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

and also I also would suggest immediately use parameters in your query!